# JS RegEx for Nz Float

Tags: javascript, regex

This RegEx should return only positive, non-zero, integers or floats:

```
^[+]?([1-9][0-9]*(?:[\.][0-9]*)?|0*\.0*[1-9][0-9]*)?$
```

Yet it is still qualifying empty strings. Is there a better way?

Comment: I fail to see why you would need that last question mark. If you leave it out, you won't match empty strings. Also, it's good practice imo to escape all characters in the same fashion. In this case [] vs \. `^\+?([1-9][0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?|0*\.0*[1-9][0-9]*)$` Test [here](https://regex101.com/r/dJ7lS0/1).

Comment: not sure about the trailing '?' either - it works properly without it now so thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^\+?([1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?|0*\.\d*[1-9]\d*)$
```

Test here: https://regex101.com/r/dJ7lS0/4

Comment: thanks Bram, but I'm getting a client-side error with this. is there anything peculiar about this approach which could cause that?

Comment: This doesn't prevent `0.000000`. You need `\.\d*[1-9]\d*` for the 2nd branch

Comment: @BramVanroy - I don't know unfortunately, I'm using this for an update to an old Google UiApp (which is deprecated) project and the error is being raised by a client handler with no useful description